# One object from list of similar objects ignoring null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have a list of objects with values that I want to write to a single same type object while disregarding the null values. The objects have a decent amount of properties therefore I'd like to do it in a generic way. I have some ideas of how to solve this, but my C# / LINQ knowledge is limited so the solutions I come up with seem more complex than necessary. I've been searching for solutions but have not found one yet.

I'm using .net core 6

Comment: Dose list contains null or object is null?

Comment: The object properties can contain null values. The list will not contain null values.

Comment: Add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
var new_list = list.Where(x => x.<property> != null).ToList();
```